# Strange behavior of listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContxt
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_link_product_distributor,
                null);
    }
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.linktoprodisarraylist = listProduct.get(position);

    holder.imgProduct = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.productimg);
    holder.txtProductName = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.txtproductname);
    holder.txtDistributorNametxt = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.txtdistributornametxt);
    holder.brand_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.barnd_nametxt);
    holder.manf_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manf_nametxt);

    holder.txtDistributorNametxt.setTag(position);
    view.setTag(holder);
    holder.imgProduct.setImageResource(holder.linktoprodisarraylist
            .getProductImgID());
    holder.txtProductName.setText(holder.linktoprodisarraylist
            .getProductName());
    holder.txtDistributorNametxt.setText(holder.linktoprodisarraylist
            .getFavDistName());
    holder.brand_name.setText(holder.linktoprodisarraylist.getBrandName());
    holder.manf_name.setText(holder.linktoprodisarraylist.getManName());
    holder.txtDistributorNametxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final String productId = arraylist.get(position).getProductID();
            TextView disname = (TextView) v;
            String Disname_value = disname.getText().toString();
            if (Disname_value.equalsIgnoreCase("Select Distributer")) {
                alreadyassigndisid = "0";
            } else {
                alreadyassigndisid = getDistributorid(Disname_value);
            }

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContxt);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row_distributor_name);
            dialog.setTitle("Select Distributer");
            dailogListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.disnamelv);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    mContxt, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listDistributorname);
            dailogListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            dailogListView
                    .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
                            TextView disname = (TextView) v;
                            disname.setText(listDistributorname
                                    .get((Integer) position));
                            int dsiId = Distributor_idlist.get(position)
                                    .getDisID();
                            insertFavProduct_DisIntoDb(userId,
                                    Integer.valueOf(alreadyassigndisid),
                                    dsiId, String.valueOf(productId),
                                    position);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I am using a listview in wich there is a textview.
A dialog is opened when the textView is clicked and the user can set a new value to the textview, but when ever I scroll the changes get reverted, and the selected distributor name is not displayed. 
Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: Because when you scroll your list, android recycle the views. So you need to store that value to the list in your custom adapter when you close your dialog and set the text to textview.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comments, your list is recycled when you scroll. You need to udpdate the list sotred in your adapter when the user enter the value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know how listview and adapter work. I recommended [this post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).
The previous comment/answer are correct. You have to store the value.